# Include/refer attributes of a table in an object in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table of Restaurants:

```
Create table Restaurants(
resID number,
resName varchar(20)
resLocation varchar(25));
```

I want to create an object 'ResObject' and in it, and add attributes of 'resID' and 'resName' from the 'Restaurants' table. Is there a way to refer a table's attribute in an object? I know about Object tables and inheritance, but they work on objects, not from table to objects. Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you want to copy the value from the table row into the object?

Comment: No, I am not trying to insert, I am trying to create an object which has specific attributes from the Restaurants table.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use inheritance and object-derived tables:

```sql
CREATE TYPE BasicRestaurant AS OBJECT(
  resid       NUMBER,
  resname     VARCHAR2(20)
) NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE Restaurant UNDER BasicRestaurant(
  reslocation VARCHAR2(25)
);

CREATE TYPE ResObject UNDER BasicRestaurant(
  value NUMBER
);
```

Then you can create the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Restaurants OF Restaurant;
CREATE TABLE ResObjects OF ResObject;
```

And the `ResObject` data-type and the `ResObjects` table will have the same data-type for the columns they share with the `Restaurants` table.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b2e48d48a8ed90a85bd6194776cee646)*